# Auto-Layout issue with bottom UIButtons in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to crate Custom-Tabbar with `UIButtons` (5 buttons in a row) on each button size exactly : w:75 h:55 which is perfectly fit on iPhone-6 and iPhone-6Plus

When i trying to add constraints ( Width Equals and margin points) on `iPhone 5` screen, buttons looses their ratio and looking like smashed a little bit.

`iPhone5` output:
[image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/51e1de65d2dd462a837efb0dc5e357c1.png]

in original layout which perfectly matched on iPhone-6Plus :

[image]

My question is, how do i succeed this layout on every device screen without messing ratio?

Regards,

Onder

Comment: Have you tried **size classes**?? using size classes you can solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think you can solve this problem with size class @Aneesh

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the **Aspect Ratio Constraint** on each of your buttons. And make sure to se the multiplier to 1 (so that width is equal to height).

[image]
[image]

Comment: My constraints looking now like that: http://prntscr.com/bb1s8e. Output : http://prntscr.com/bb1sjq. Something still wrong ..

Comment: I saw that you have width equal constraints. You need to remove that. You set them to 75 pixels, which may not fit on all screen sizes.

Comment: Before adding Aspect Ratio, these constraints are correct?  http://prntscr.com/bb1za7 or do i have to add only height  constraint too?

Comment: I don't know what your super view is so you may need to provide a bit more context here.

Comment: You don't need to add a height constraint because you don't want to specify the height. You want to height to be computed according to the width of the button. So the aspect ratio constraint equals to 1 is good enough. However, you do need to set proper width constraints for you buttons though. What you want is to make all the buttons same width with equal width constraints. You only need 4 of these with constraints: button 1 width == button 2 width, button 2 width == button 3 width and etc.

Comment: I have a UIView which acting as container for my buttons : http://prntscr.com/bb24uf

Comment: I will suggest remove the container `UIView` . It is not needed. And you have to remove the top space to superview here too: http://prntscr.com/bb1za7. That top space is also kind of height constraint if you think about it carefully.

Comment: I removed UIview container and top space to superview. The result has same :(

Comment: Have you also add the width constraints I mentioned above?

Comment: I created sample app, If you have a time would you like to check it? https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/8abea73b33e7cc89b3fa6d1603d56bbe20160602115757/521979

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIImageView's contentMode property to .ScaleAspectFit

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: Which has an imageView property (public var imageView: UIImageView? { get }). So button.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

Comment: I am going to try it now. I will let you know if it's going to fix the layout-issue